# Javascript callback function get parent variable value

Tags: javascript

```
function foo(callback){
    var a = 1;
    
    return callback();
}

foo(function(){ 
    if ( a == 1 ) { alert(a); }
});
```

I try to make a callback can access parent var, but I get undefine

anyone know how to achieve this

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: **It can't,** that's why you can simulate private state through closures in JS. You can pass it's (current) value to the callback *(or in the case of objects, a reference)* but not the variable; which means, the callback doesn't "notice" when the value of `a` changes; all it has is the value given. And you can not change the value of the variable from the callback. If you explain what **exactly** you are trying to achieve, we can help you work around the problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make `a` an argument and pass it to the callback:

```
function foo(callback){
    var a = 1;
    
    return callback(a);
}

foo(function(a){ 
    if ( a == 1 ) { alert(a); }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try sending variable "a" in callback function as parameter.

```js
function foo(callback){
    var a = 1;
    
    return callback(a);
}

foo(function(a){ 
    if ( a == 1 ) { alert(a); }
});
```